# Image request have parameters attached to prevent caching. How do I stop this behaviour?

Tags: ee, cache

The following image requests has parameters appended, presumably to prevent local browser caching.

`<img class="sml24" src="{global:theme_url}/responsive/images/24hours-sml.svg" alt="24hours">24 Hour Production</span>`

`https://www.example.net/themes/user/site_themes/default/responsive/images/24hours-sml.svg?1556660937802`

This behaviour seems to be added by Expression Engine and the outcome is several requests for the same image.

Can someone offer some insight?

Is this in fact EE, or is it something one of my predecessors has manually added to the codebase

Comment: Based on what you posted, no, this is not caused by native ExpressionEngine functionality. It might be a server configuration (`.htaccess` rule maybe) or an add-on causing that behavior. You'll have to add more details to your question (EE version, server infrastructure info, list of installed add-ons) for us to help you, unless someone else chimes in. I'm guessing it's server, infrastructure, or add-on related behavior.

Comment: Most EE add-ons that provide cache-busting strings like this also require an EE tag to be included in the link that you want to cache-bust.  Since your template code has no such tags, it looks like in your case the strings are being added via .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  What should I look for in `.htaccess`?